# Inserting reservation record to php database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, insert

I have created a reservation form for housing. The user fills the form out and submits it. A reservation record is supposed to be made which is then inserted into a reservations table.

This is the code that is being inserted into the database as a record

```
$reservationsTable = "Reservations";
$r1 = (rand(11111,99999));

createReservationRecord($reservationsTable, [$r1, $date,$dormRecord[id], $_POST["CWID"], $_POST["firstName"], $_POST["lastName"], $_POST["class"], $_POST["gender"], $_POST["fullyEquippedKitchen"], $_POST["laundry"], $_POST["specialNeeds"]]);
```

These are the functions that transform this data:

```
 function createRecord($table, $values) {
    echo "This is working";
    return insertInto($table, ["name","class","specialNeeds","laundry","fullyEquippeKkitchen","roomsAvailable","roomsReserved","roomCapacity"], $values);

}

function createReservationRecord($table, $values) {
    echo "<br> in createReservationRecord(), table is \"$table\", values are ".print_r ($values)."\n<br>";
    return insertInto($table, ["id","reservationTime","ra_id","CWID","firstName","lastName","class", "gender","kitchen", "laundry", "specialNeeds"], $values);
}

function insertInto($table, $columns, $values) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(", ", $columns) . ") VALUES (" . implode(", ", $values) . ")";
    echo "Inserting a new record with SQL Statement: $sql\n<br>";
    return query($sql);
}
```

When I use print_r($values) to check the array of values it only returns 1. I'm just not sure why the data being inserted is being read wrong.

Comment: Why so many lavels of database abstraction? And after doing all that you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection. Delete all this and use PDO

Comment: This is just so I can see the data as it is being inserted and when I am sure there are no bugs I can condense the code.

Comment: doubling and tripling the work to produce bad code. Get it right the first time

Comment: This thing is full of bugs, and you're also re-inventing the wheel here. What you're building is a form of ORM, and there's already many out there that are working, tested, and have community support if you get into a jam. Look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/)
and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) as examples. Don't try and roll your own or you'll just make a bunch of mistakes that can cost you huge.

Comment: The biggest problem here is a reckless lack of [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) which has created a number of [serious problems](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change here , use back tick in cumn and single quotes in values

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (`" . implode("`, `", $columns) . "`) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "')";
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't see error in your code but try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ". $table." (" . implode(", ", $columns) . ") VALUES (" . implode(", ", $values) . ")";
```